# How to get hiddenfield's value with name equal to the text inside a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get id from the selected button among many buttons having same class but different id

```
<div data-seat="C14" title="C14" id="c14" class="aao row__seat sits-price--expansive" data-price = "30" >
                        <input type="hidden" name="C14" value="True">
                        </div>

<div data-seat="C14" id="c15" title="C15" class="aao row__seat sits-price--expansive" data-price = "30" >
                        <input type="hidden" name="C15" value="True">
                        </div>
```

i am able to get id of the button but can't change the respective hidden fields value to false
I am using jquery ,
this is my effort

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.aao').on('click', function(){
            var i = this.id;
            var hidfield = $('input[name=i]').val();
            var val=hiddenField.val();
            hidfield.val(val=="true"?"false":"true");
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youll have to append the variable out of the string

```
var hidfield = $('input[name='+i+']');
```

Comment: This works just fine. This is what i wanted to do thanks!!